# RepositoryEventHandler not invoked

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I'm working on a project and I need to get notified when an entity is created or updated. But unfortunately, `@RepositoryEventHandler` did not work. So I prepare a simple version but I had no luck either. Below, I have written all components that I have thought it would be needed for regenerating my problem.

My Configuration

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "db")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"db"})
//@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
public class Config {

@Bean
@Autowired
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setShowSql(Boolean.TRUE);
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

    factory.setPackagesToScan("db");
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factory.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() throws Exception {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    p.put("driverClassName", "org.h2.Driver");
    p.put("user", "admin");
    p.put("password", "123");
    DataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource("jdbc:h2:~/desktop/test;", p);
    return ds;
}

@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager(DataSource ds) {
    DataSourceTransactionManager txManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
    try {
        txManager.setDataSource(getDataSource());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return txManager;
}

private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.charSet", "UTF-8");
    properties.put("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", "false");
    properties.put("hibernate.max_fetch_depth", "3");

    properties.put("hibernate.connection.autocommit", "false");
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.release_mode", "on_close");

    return properties;
}
```

}

My POJO definition:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
public class Entity {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3501352854892096642L;


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id ;

private String name ;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

My Repository:

```
    @RepositoryRestResource
public interface EntityRep extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Entity,Long> {
}
```

and at last, this is my event handler definition class:

```
@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler(Entity.class)
public class EventHandler {

    @HandleBeforeSave
    @HandleBeforeCreate
    public void doSomething(Entity e){
        System.out.println("Hi...");
    }
}
```

I should be noted that I'm using Spring Data Rest 2.6.4, Hibernate 5.2.10.Final and Tomcat 8.5.12 for the container. Moreover, I have used the following configuration for my Web.xml :

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>db</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What does "did not work" mean? Doesn't it get called? Do you get an exception? ...

Comment: It does't get called.